# Protected Internal properties vs Protected properties and Resharper

Tags: c#, .net, properties, resharper, protected

I've just picked up Resharper and have been playing around converting fields to properties. I want these properties to be protected, but Resharper doesn't want to give me that option. Instead there is only a Protected Internal option. This has me thinking. Either there is a rule somewhere that properties should always be 'protected internal' rather than just 'protected'. Or I just don't know how to use resharper. Which is it?

Update: Contacted Jetbrains themselves and they have identified this behaviour as a bug and raised a bug report. Marc's answer is essentially correct on the usage of 'protected internal' so he gets the big tick.

Comment: Did you declare the class public?  The default is internal.  Declaring properties of an internal class as internal is fairly silly, it requires a refactoring tool when you refactor to make the class public.  Although that does make sure you'll go from the demo version to the retail version.

Comment: Yes - the class was declared as public. Infact, it wasn't at the start, but I created a test project with just the class and purposely declared it public. I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are the fields at the moment? `public`? I wonder if you have some code in other types that is already touching the properties, and thus would break if they were *just* `protected`. I don't know how resharper feels about it, but it is not necessary (or even particularly common) to make things `protected internal` - so `protected` *should* be a reasonable option.

Comment: The fields were protected to start off with and the code compiles fine with the properties as just protected